# BNFC is not parsing individual functions

Tags: bnfc

I have the following BNFC code:

```
GFDefC. GoalForm ::= Constraint ;
GFDefT. GoalForm ::= True ;
GFDefA. GoalForm ::= GoalForm "," GoalForm ;
GFDefO. GoalForm ::= GoalForm ";" GoalForm ;

ConFr. Constraint ::= Var "#" Term ;

TVar. Term ::= UnVar;
TFun. Term ::= Fun ;

FDef. Fun  ::= FunId "(" [Arg] ")" ;
ADecl. Arg ::= Term ;
separator Arg "," ;

...
```

However, the following is not parsed

`fun(X)`

while it parses the one below

`x # fun(Y)`

so to sum up, it parses the function as a part of constraints, but not individually.
It should parse both of them.

Could anyone point out why?

Answer (score 1):

You should set your `entrypoints` properly.

As you're parsing `x # fun(Y)` successfully, I assume you have set your `entrypoints` to `Constraint` and using the generated `pConstraint` function to parse your expressions. Then, you can change your rules of `Constraint` to

```
ConNoVar. Constraint ::= Term ;
ConFr.    Constraint ::= Var "#" Term ;
```

Aternatively, you can add `Term` to your `entrypoints` and invoke `pTerm` to parse your function terms.